# Multiprocessing.dummy, multiprocessing, and map, how to perform error handling?

Tags: python, error-handling, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I'm using the `multiprocessing.dummy` module to do some concurrent processing.  I'm making `HTTP` requests, and there is a possibility that the object will not have any data returned.  In this case I need to capture the `AttributeError` and move on.

I tried capturing it in the object itself, and still received the error, the only thing that worked was a `try/except` on the `pool.map` call itself.  I'm wondering why this is, and if this is the best way to do error handling for `multiprocessing` and `map` functions?

Here is some of my code for reference:

```
all_commits = []
    projects = [Project(value['id']) for value in project_data.values()]
    def process_projects(project):
        if project.name in bad_names.keys():
            project.name = bad_names[project.name]
        project.return_results(rest, all_commits)
    pool = ThreadPool(8)
    pool.map(process_projects, projects)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print 'All data gathered.'
    print 'Number of commits: {}'.format(len(all_commits))
    fieldnames = get_fieldnames(
        'ods_gerrit.staging_gerrit_commits',
        settings.REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO)
    s3_file = ('staging_gerrit_commits_{}.csv.gz'.format(
        date.today())
    )
    with gzip.open(s3_file, 'wb') as outf:
        writer = DictWriter(
            outf,
            fieldnames=fieldnames,
            extrasaction='ignore',
            delimiter='|'
        )
        cnt = 0
        pool = ThreadPool(8)
        try:
            pool.map(process_commits, all_commits)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

Then here is my `Commit` object code and the function that is being called by the `map` function:

```
class Commit(object):
    def __init__(self, rev_id, change_id, full_id):
        self.rev_id = rev_id
        self.change_id = change_id
        self.full_id = full_id

    def clean_data(self, _dict):
        for key, value in _dict.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                self.clean_data(_dict[key])
            else:
                try:
                    _dict[key] = _dict[key].encode(
                        'utf_8',
                        'replace'
                    ).encode('string_escape').replace('|', '[pipe]')
                except AttributeError:
                    continue

    def get_data(self, ger_obj):
        print 'Getting data for a commit for {f_id}'.format(
            f_id=self.full_id
        )
        endpoint = (r'/changes/{c_id}/revisions/{r_id}/commit'.format(
            c_id=self.change_id,
            r_id=self.rev_id
        ))
        try:
            self.data = ger_obj.get(endpoint)
        except HTTPError:
            try:
                endpoint = (r'/changes/{f_id}/revisions/{r_id}/commit'.format(
                    f_id=self.full_id,
                    r_id=self.rev_id
                ))
                self.data = ger_obj.get(endpoint)
            except HTTPError:
                logging.warning('Neither endpoint returned data: {ep}'.format(
                    ep=endpoint
                ))
                raise HTTPError()
        except ReadTimeout:
            logging.warning('Read Timeout occurred for a commit.  Endpoint: '
                            '{ep/}'.format(ep=endpoint))
            return
        self.data['change_id'] = self.change_id
        self.data['proj_branch_id'] = self.full_id
        self.data['revision_id'] = self.rev_id
        self.data['commitid'] = self.data.get('commit')
        self.data['name'] = self.data.get('committer')['name']
        self.data['email'] = self.data.get('committer')['email']
        self.data['date'] = self.data.get('committer')['date']
        hash = md5()
        hash.update(json.dumps(self.data).encode('utf-8'))
        self.data['etl_checksum_md5'] = hash.hexdigest()
        self.data['etl_process_status'] = settings.ETL_PROCESS_STATUS
        self.data['etl_datetime_local'] = settings.ETL_DATETIME_LOCAL
        self.data['etl_pdi_version'] = settings.ETL_PDI_VERSION
        self.data['etl_pdi_build_version'] = settings.ETL_PDI_BUILD_VERSION
        self.data['etl_pdi_hostname'] = settings.ETL_PDI_HOSTNAME
        self.data['etl_pdi_ipaddress'] = settings.ETL_PDI_IPADDRESS
        self.clean_data(self.data)


    def write_data(self, writer):
        print 'Writing a commit for {f_id}'.format(f_id=self.full_id)
        writer.writerow(self.data)
```

And the controller function:

```
def process_commits(commit):
    print 'On commit #{}'.format(cnt)
    unique_id = commit.change_id + commit.rev_id
    if not id_search(unique_ids, unique_id):
        try:
            commit.get_data(rest)
        except HTTPError:
            pass
        try:
            commit.write_data(writer=writer)
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            logging.warning(
                '{data} caused a Unicode Encode Error.'.format(
                    data=commit.data
                ))
            pass
        global cnt
        cnt += 1
```

Comment: If you are not sure where exactly the AttributeError is fired, try to wrap entire `process_commits` in try..except and use `traceback.print_exc()` in except part. I guess it is `self.data` somewhere.

Comment: It happens in the commit `get_data` method.  I tried handling for that and still got the exception though.  It seems like it needed to be on the thread level because it was the `pool.map_asynch.get()` if I remember correctly.

Comment: `multiprocessing.pool` catches exceptions in workers and reraises them in the main thread.
It is weird that `AttributeError` is not catched in the worker, it should.
Try `logging.error(traceback.format_exc())` in except part.

Also, you are using `DictWriter` from 8 threads, i doubt this is safe.